# How to get the document ID SharePoint Designer workflow

Tags: workflow

I want to know how can I get the current Item's document Id in a content publishing approval workflow using SharePoint Designer 2013?

Answer (score 1):

By using below query I was able to get the right output. Here I selected the Pages Library as source of data and Document Id Value as output result. Where it's ID matches with current item's ID.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Current Item:ID` will be satisfying your requirement

Comment: It gives the ID of the Item in library. I have ID e.g. 100,101,102 etc. and the document Id is Content-Page-8020, Content-Page-8021 and so on.